# Calculating Covariance when three coins are flipped

Tags: probability

Three fair coins are flipped. Let x be the number of heads. Let y equal to 1 if all coins land the same outcome I.e hhh or ttt, and 0 if otherwise. Calculate Cov(X,Y)

Comment: Hi, can you post what you tried so people here can help you better?

Answer (score 1):

$Cov_{X,Y} = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$

We have 8 outcomes.

HHH $\implies XY = 3$
for all other combinations $XY = 0$

$E[XY] = \frac 38$

$E[X] = \frac 32, E[Y] = \frac 14$

$E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = 0$

Which isn't really a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Note $Y=1$ iff $X=3$ or $X=0$.

$X$ is Binomial(3,1/2), so $P(X=x) = \binom{3}{x} (1/2)^x (1-1/2)^{3-x}$ for $x=0,1,2,3$.

You can write down $P(X=x,Y=y)$ from the statements above. $P(X=1,Y=1)=P(X=2,Y=2)=P(X=0,Y=0)=P(X=3,Y=0)=0$. Now, $P(X=1,Y=0) = P(X=1), P(X=2,Y=0)=P(X=2). And $P(X=3,Y=1)=P(X=3), P(X=0,Y=1)=P(X=0)$.

Now, you can simply calculate the covariance by computing $E[X] = \sum_x x P(X=x)$, computing $P(Y=y) = \sum_x P(X=x,Y=y)$ for $y=0,1$ and then computing $E[Y] = \sum_y y P(Y=y)$. Then, you can compute $E[XY] = \sum_{x,y} xy P(X=x,Y=y)$ and note that $cov(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$.